# search in matrix with sorted columns if number exist

Tags: java, matrix

```
private static int binaricSearch(int[][] a, int num)
{
    final int FIRST_COLUMN = 0;
    int top = a.length -1 , bottom = 0, mid;

    while(top >= bottom){
        if(top == bottom)
            return top;
        mid = (top + bottom)/2;
        if(num >= a[mid][FIRST_COLUMN] && num < a[mid][FIRST_COLUMN])
            return mid;
        else if(num > a[mid][FIRST_COLUMN])
            bottom = mid + 1;
        else if(num < a[mid][FIRST_COLUMN])
            top = mid-1;
    }
    return top;
}
public static boolean findInMatrix(int[][] a, int num)
{
    int indexRow = binaricSearch(a,num);
    for(int j=0 ; j<a[0].length; j++  ) {
        if (a[indexRow][j] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] matrix =    {  {0,5,1,2,3},
                           {6,8,7,10,4},
                           {13,14,12,15,11},
                           {17,19,16,22,24}
                        };
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    int numToFind = 14;

    System.out.println("\nThe Number: "+numToFind);
    if(findInMatrix(matrix,numToFind) == true)
        System.out.println("\n"+numToFind+" Found in the matrix!");
    else
        System.out.println("\n"+numToFind+" NOT Found in the matrix!");
}
```

*The implementations attached above ^^

hey, i'm trying to find a number in 2D array, with sorted columns, in Run Time complexity of O(n).

But it find only part the elements.

Outputs:

Found, For: 0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 10, 19, 16, 22, 24

NOT Found, For:  4, 14, 12, 15, 11

print nothing (i think its stuck in the loop) For: 6, 13

Comment: Please post the code in the post, not as images to external web pages.

Comment: What exactly is `n`?

Comment: @PM77-1  did you mean numToFind? numToFind = 14 in this case, the other cases listed below the Outputs (Found/Not Found/nothing)

Comment: tldr; binary search only works for sorted arrays. In your case, your 2D array should be sorted row-wise as well as column-wise.

Comment: I know, thats why the "binaricsearch" method separated from "findInMatrix" method. "binaricsearch" for the sorted columns, and then "binaricsearch" for the unsorted rows.